# Why did my Flask web-app deployed on IBM CloudFoundry through CLI stop all of a sudden?

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I deployed my application on IBM Cloud on May 12, 2020.

I opened the link to my app today and found it was not working. I visited the Resources tab on my IBM Cloud account and this is what I saw.

[image]

In the Activity Feed section, you can see that my application stopped mysteriously on May 22, 2020. I clicked on "Full details" but it was empty too.

[image]

How can I restore the web-application and why did it stop all of a sudden?

EDIT: This is a free plan. It was running fine until today. No terms were violated either. Upon visiting the app URL, I get a 404 error.

Comment: Is this a free or paid Cloud Foundry plan? Did the app crash? Did it violate any terms and was stopped?

Comment: This is a free plan. It was running fine until today. No terms were violated either. Upon visiting the app URL, I get a 404 error.

Comment: If it is not running, it is a 404. Could you restart it, then try to retrieve all the recent logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you ran into this [restriction for an IBM Cloud Lite Account](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#liteaccount).

> After 10 days of no development activity, your apps go to sleep. You can wake up your apps by continuing to work on them.

You need to change your app every few days. Lite accounts are meant to try out few things, then move up to [Pay-As-You-Go accounts](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#paygo). You can still use the same free resources, have to access to even more free services, but you need to identify yourself by providing credit card information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a doubt though. In the docs it is mentioned that "If you change your app, you must upload those changes by entering the cf push command again. The cf command line interface uses your previous options and your responses to the prompts to update any running instances of your app with the new bits of code." If I push my app now, wouldn't it create a new app (which will not even deploy since my existing app already uses 256 MB)? How is it going to know if I'm creating a new app or developing the existing one?

Comment: You push it with the same options, especially same name. Thus, it is going to update the app. That is a typical development cycle.